# CSS+JS recources and Blazor .NET Core 3.0 application compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, .net-core-3.0

I've created standard Blazor application in MS VS 2019 and compiled it.

As result I have folder bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\ and files

- Properties\
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.runtimeconfig.dev.json
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.runtimeconfig.json
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.deps.json
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.Views.pdb
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.Views.dll
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.exe
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.dll
- BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.pdb
- appsettings.json
- appsettings.Development.json

in it.
When I start BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.exe and open http://localhost:5000/ , no css and js files can be loaded (app returns 404 for CSS and JS files).

But if I copy folder wwwroot from root project folder into bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\ and restart BlazorApp1_FOR_DELETE.exe , all resource files are loaded in browser correctly.

How to compile all resource files (CSS, JS...) from wwwroot into compiled version of my app, when I run Build - Rebuild solution?

Comment: You need to publish your app running `dotnet publish` and use the publihed .exe if you want to start it from the .exe

Comment: Thank you again! :) But, Just for curiosity, could these files be compiled into app DLL instead to store them in wwwroot?

Comment: Do you mean embeded as resources?

Comment: Yep, something like that. I've tried to mark them as Embedded Resource and deleted wwwroot, but in this case app returns 404 for those files links.

Comment: You can publish your app in one .exe file with .net core 3. It will be depacted at 1st run but you can't embed your css and js as resource because the browser is not going to understand.

Comment: Not sure it works with Blazor, I never test it

Comment: Can you please write an answer - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish your app running `dotnet publish` and use the published .exe if you want to start it from the .exe.

You can publish your app in one .exe file with .net core 3. It will be unpacked at 1st run but you can't embed your css and js as resource because the browser is not going to understand.

`dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true`